# path attribute of forward tag in struts-config.xml file

Tags: struts

```
<action-mappings>
        <action name="loginAction" path="/loginAction"
            type="com.xx.yy.actions.LoginAction" scope="request"
            validate="false">
            <forward name="landingPage" path="landingpage" />
            <forward name="error" path="errorpage" />
        </action>

        <action name="admin" path="/adminAction"
            type="com.xx.yy.actions.AdminHome" scope="request"
            validate="true" input="/jsp/login.jsp">
            <forward name="success" path="/jsp/admin/admin.jsp" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/jsp/admin/admin.jsp" />
        </action>
</action-mappings>
```

In the above code path attribute of forward tag is landingpage for action loginAction .
So in this case control takes to which page or action?In this context what is landingpage?Is it a jsp or another action?

In admin action path attribute of forward tags are jsps so its clear that control will be directed to jsp depending on logic in action class.

Comment: It depends on the result returned by the action.

Comment: yes tiles are there..

Answer (score 1):

In that line...

```
<forward name="landingPage" path="landingpage" />
```

...the `path` attribute may be an [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) configuration name.